# Does Sweave have a auto-fill option?

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

When I use R Sweave, I could not find the auto-fill option, which is available on other TEX editors. I prefer to have this auto-fill option, because I sometimes cannot remember the complete command spelling.

Comment: Auto-fill is a feature of the particular text editor you are using, not of R or Sweave. The editor RStudio has some auto fill when using `knitr`, probably `Sweave` as well.

Comment: @Gregor How can I enable this option?

Comment: It is enabled by default. Make sure you are in a file of the correct type, and see, e.g., Code/Insert Chunk. If you are not seeing what you want, you should provide a much more specific example including a **short** sample file and a line that you expect would auto-complete.